# Kivy: size of layout doesn't update on app start

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy, toggle, kivy-language

I am quite new to kivy and python, first question here... So, I want to hide the layout if the checkbox is empty manipulating size and opacity properties. It works as expected if you use checkboxes, but when app run, there is empty space. I tried to use constructor and schedule_once functions to change size to [0,0], and looks like size property changes, but still there an empty space you can see in screenshot.

P.S.
I have a hypothesis, that the issue somehow related to kv file includes because I tried to create a minimalistic example for this question, and that... works fine, using just main.kv and main.py.

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

kivy.require('1.11.0')

kv = """
#:import utils kivy.utils

<ValuesGridLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    row_default_height: 30
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    spacing: 3

<MainPanelLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    text: "Some content"

<MainPanel>:
    kinetic_container: kinetic_container
    thread_container: thread_container
    padding: 20, 20, 20, 0
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    padding: [0, 10]
                    cols: 1
                    spacing: 30
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height

                    BoxLayout:
                        CheckBox:
                            size_hint: (None, None)
                            size: [20,20]
                            on_active:
                                root.toggleParameters(self.active, root.kinetic_container)

                        MainPanelLabel:
                            text: "Kinetic values:"
                            color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#f6711b')
                            font_size: '20sp'

                    ValuesGridLayout:
                        id: kinetic_container
                        visible: False
                        size: [500, 200] if self.visible else [0, 0]
                        opacity: 1 if self.visible else 0
                        disabled: not self.visible

                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel

                    BoxLayout:
                        CheckBox:
                            padding: 20
                            size_hint: (None, None)
                            size: [20,20]
                            on_active:
                                root.toggleParameters(self.active, root.thread_container)

                        MainPanelLabel:
                            text: "Thread values:"
                            color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#f6711b')
                            font_size: '20sp'

                    ValuesGridLayout:
                        id: thread_container
                        visible: False
                        size: [500, 200] if self.visible else [0, 0]
                        opacity: 1 if self.visible else 0
                        disabled: not self.visible

                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel
                        MainPanelLabel

<MainFrame>:
    id: screen_manager
    Screen:
        name: "Initial"
        MainPanel

"""


class MainPanel(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.initializeSize(), 0)

    def toggleParameters(self, instance, object):
        if instance:
            object.visible = True
        else:
            object.visible = False

    def initializeSize(self):
        self.kinetic_container.size = [0, 0]
        self.thread_container.size = [0, 0]


class MainFrame(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Builder.load_string(kv)
    SomeApp().run()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: I‘ve looked through the source code, you’re using mixed tab/space formatting, that might be causing issues. It’s also unreadable from the UI because of it. Consider putting the code in this format too, it’ll help not having to hold 4 files in your mind: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Community-Guidelines#asking-for-help-on-kivy-and-kivy-users

Comment: @JurajFiala Thanks for your corrections, guidelines, and your time, I have updated the code.

Comment: If there issue still occurs, try also making a MCVE out of it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. It might even help you solve the problem in the process.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue still occurs :c

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure *what* exactly causes to the buggy behaviour, but here is the culprit.

```
<ValuesGridLayout@GridLayout>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    ...
```

Here you set the height to `self.minimum_height`. But when you use the widget, you override that:

```
ValuesGridLayout:
    id: kinetic_container
    size: [500, 200] if self.visible else [0, 0]
    ...
```

(Note: setting the width doesn’t actually do anything, since `size_hint_x` is still 1.)

> **Speculation**: Properties only dispatch events if the value is different. When I tried debugging it, on the launch of the app the class definition of `height` was called first, then the instance definition, then the class definition again.  If you’d have used `self.minimum_height` instead of `200`, it would have worked, so it looks like the event dispatched by the change triggers something during the initial widget setup.

#### Solution

You can move all the properties into the class rule:

```
<ValuesGridLayout@GridLayout>:
    visible: False
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height if self.visible else 0
    opacity: 1 if self.visible else 0
    disabled: not self.visible
    cols: 1
    row_default_height: 30
    spacing: 3
```

Now you just need

```
ValuesGridLayout:
    id: kinetic_container
    MainPanelLabel
    ...
```

and

```
ValuesGridLayout:
    id: thread_container
    MainPanelLabel
    ...
```

That’s all.

#### Bonus tips:

- `size`, `padding` ([`ReferenceListProperty`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty)’s) work with tuples, so you can just do `size: 200, 500`
- You do not need to do `root.kinetic_container`, simply `kinetic_container` will do, see the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets) for scopes of id’s
- `toggleParameters()` is unnecessary, you can just do `on_active: kinetic_container.visible = self.active`
- Instead of defining an empty `__init__()`, just do

  ```py
  class MainFrame(ScreenManager):
      pass
  ```

Happy hacking!

Comment: @NobleFox, if this answer helped, I’d appreciate if you’d mark it as accepted. :-)